# Revert .git deletion

Tags: xcode, git

I have a repo on my computer (No remote), I was trying to reinit my repo but Unfortunately I lost all my changes.

What happened:

- I did a commit to save all the changes
- I reverted the commit (that’s where I lost the changes I guess)
- I deleted the .git folder and made a new one.
- Realized that I lost all my changes on revert, but I don’t have the logs anymore the cherry pick the commit.

I tried to restore the .git folder, through the trash bin and through recovery softwares but In vain..

Is there any solution or the data is completely lost?

Ps: it’s an XCode project and I’m on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the totality of what Git stores during a repository lifetime is under `.git`. If you wiped out this directory, you discarded the complete repository, just as if it never existed before. Only remains the files checked out so far and maybe `.gitignore` files and such. :-(

Still, it was a very good idea to commit all the changes even if reverting it afterwards. When doing this, you ensure yourself you'll almost never loose data… providing `.git` keeps its integrity.

If however your were able to retrieve some *fragments* of your former `.git` repository out of the trashcan, especially a list of objects, then there's a (very small) hope. Otherwise, I'm afraid there's nothing to do anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know which files I should be looking specifically?

I deleted using the terminal rm -rf, it doesn't seem to be found in the trashcan

Comment: If you used `rm -rf`, it will indeed have totally disappeared. This doesn't directly interact with desktop environment. Only remain the recovery softwares you quoted. You want to retrieve mainly git objects, which are gzipped files named after their SHA1 sum (40 hexadecimal characters). The names would probably have disappeared too. Git is able to recognize a file of its own, for instance using `git cat-file` but if you're working on your regular machine's hard drive, you'll have a hard time trying to find them back among all other deleted files.

Comment: Yes.. I tried with many softwares, none of them seems to find the files